# date.php and archive.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date, wordpress-theming, archive

I have a noob question. Currently I have the files:

archive.php and date.php

both have different date format. Using the calendar widget, whenever I clicked the specific date for example "March 10, 2020" post, it goes to the date.php page which has the correct date format.

But using the archive widget which has the month and year format, whenever I click a date for example all "Feb 2020" or "March 2020" post the page still goes to the date.php page and not the archive.php. How do I direct the archives to the archive.php page? or am I using the wrong page?

Comment: Is date a custom post type?

Comment: you mean custom post in function? no it's not, it's from the widgets calendar and archive date, the date when the blog post is published